# connect to VM with SSH in java

Tags: java, ssh, virtual-machine

I am new to java and I want to write a code that
connects a Linux machine with SSH (with IP and password) make a directiry, and copy my file to there.
how can I do this?

this is how it is done in python:

```
        ssh.connect(automationGW, port=22,
                    username='root', password=passwordGW)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(mkdir /opt/Home/test_files)
        cmdResult = stdout.read()
        scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
        scp.put(directory + '/finalDir/' + pcapFile, '/opt/Home/test_files')
        ssh.close()
```

what is the  equivalent command in java
for: `ssh.exec_command`
and  `SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())`
and  `scp.put`
?

thank you very much.

Comment: You can use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

It has well documented [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) as well.

You can use these examples to write a program for creating directory and uploading file easily.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.